# convert QBytearray to QBitarray

Tags: arrays, qt, qbytearray

How can i convert a QBytearray to a QBitarray?
Qt manual says this:

```
for(int i=0; i<8; ++i) {
    for(int b=0; b<byteArray.count();b++) {
        bits.setBit( i*8+b, byteArray.at(i)&(1<<(7-b)) );
    }
```

But this causes a runtime error. 
Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The loop seems strange it is indexing the byte array with i which goes to 8, but the byteArray might not have 8 elements. Just switching the loop limits should work:

```
for(int i = 0; i < byteArray.count(); ++i) {
  for(int b = 0; b < 8; b++) {
    bits.setBit( i * 8 + b, byteArray.at(i) & (1 << (7 - b)) );
}
```

Comment: thank you, and how would you convert a uint16 to a qbitarray?

Comment: @BastiAn, QBitArray is a bit of a misnomer and doesn't easily stream; you're better off with a different class.

Answer (score 1):

We hardcoded the Map for ex  **m_binaryMap.insert("A","1010");**

```
QBitArray returnBitAr(const QByteArray &dataTOconvert)
    {
        QBitArray bitAr;
        int count = 0;
        bitAr.resize(4*dataTOconvert.length());
        QString byteData = dataTOconvert.data();
        for(int i = 0; i< dataTOconvert.length(); i++){
            QString value =  m_binaryMap.value(byteData.at(i));
            for(int j = 0; j< value.length(); j++){
                if(value.at(j) == "1"){
                    bitAr.setBit(count);
                }
                ++count;
            }
        }
        return bitAr;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Better looks variant to convert:

QByteArray -> QBitArray

```
QByteArray bytes = ...;

// Create a bit array of the appropriate size
QBitArray bits(bytes.count()*8);
 
// Convert from QByteArray to QBitArray
for(int i=0; i<bytes.count(); ++i)
    for(int b=0; b<8; ++b)
        bits.setBit(i*8+b, bytes.at(i)&(1<<b));
```

QBitArray -> QByteArray

```
QBitArray bits = ...;
 
// Resulting byte array
QByteArray bytes;
 
// Convert from QBitArray to QByteArray
for(int b=0; b<bits.count(); ++b)
    bytes[b/8] = (bytes.at(b/8) | ((bits[b]?1:0)<<(b%8)));
```